# Angular JS slide animation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using v 1.1.4 so that I can use the ng-animate directive with ng-show.

I've got a fade working great on one part of my app, but having a bit of trouble getting a slide in panel to behave.

If I take the 'right: 0;' off the targetDiv, then it slides in nicely, but then when the animation is complete, it jumps to the left side of the screen (as expected, as the classes are removed on complete).

But if I keep the 'right: 0;' on the .targetDiv then the animation never runs, and it simply just shows the div, rather than sliding it.

I'd put together a fiddle, but can't seem to get it working with the CDN version of 1.1.4

Any help much appreciated!

**CSS**

```
.slideFromRight-show-setup {
  -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
  transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.slideFromRight-show-setup {
  right: -100%;
}

.slideFromRight-show-setup.slideFromRight-show-start {
  right: 0;
}

.targetDiv {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="targetDiv" ng-show="detailPanel.visible" ng-animate="'slideFromRight'">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked out that the ng-animate directive doesn't work very well for CSS properties that don't have a default - it works great for opacity (where the default opacity is 100%), but not for absolutely positioned right: 0; as right is not 0 in default state.

Using both the JS & CSS3 parts of ng-animate (http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive:ngAnimate) means that I can do a dirty hack to get a class added on complete, then removed on hide:

```
myApp.animation('slideFromRight-show', function() {
  return {
    setup : function(element) {
    },
    start : function(element, done, memo) {
      var timer = setTimeout(function(){
        element.addClass("opened");
        done();
      }, 500);
    }
  };
});

myApp.animation('slideFromRight-hide', function() {
  return {
    setup : function(element) {
      element.removeClass("opened");
    },
    start : function(element, done, memo) {
      var timer = setTimeout(function(){
        done();
      }, 500);
    }
  };
});
```

This feels dirty, and if someone can come up with a better answer, that would be ace - but this works for the prototype I'm building right now.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna take a look at [Angular Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)'s Carousel directive and see how they accomplished the sliding effect (it's not done through `ngAnimate` though).

Alternatively, I've wrote an article on how to patch Angular Bootstrap's Carousel implementation with a jQuery-enabled `ngAnimate` definition which might be helpful to you:

http://gsklee.im/post/50254705713/nganimate-your-angularjs-apps-with-css3-and-jquery#nganimate-custom-directives

Comment: Thanks for sharing Kay, I ended up with a bunch of other things needing to be triggered before, during, and after my animation so went with what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me ui.bootstrap will help you. Here is basic example http://surecode.me/aknoblog/